# Module 'socket" not found

Tags: sockets, dll, lua, lua-5.1

[Error when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOrFd.png)
I created a program in ZeroBrane, and I compiled it using srlua.
However, since it has some usage of socket get requests, it seems like it is looking for files such as socket.dll to be in the same folder

**I am aware that there are other questions just like this.**
My socket should be somewhere in my lua folder, but I have found core.dll under the socket, which didn't work.

I'm wondering if I'm approaching this right, and looking for a way to make sure the program can find these files. (it seems to be more than one file required)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `socket.lua` in a folder that is available through `package.path` (or have to be packaged together with your script with srlua) and you also need to have `socket\core.dll` available through `package.cpath`, as `socket.lua` does `require "socket.core"` and expects to find a DLL that implements that.